# Embedding and Extending Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

In the [Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html#(part._embedding-and-extending)) [1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html#(part._embedding-and-extending)) there is mention of embedding and extending the interpreter, although no demonstration/explanation exists for doing the two together. Specifically, is there a way to embed the interpreter inside of a C program and pass a pointer to a function to add to the interpreter? As an example of this kind of functionality, the elisp interpreter inside of Emacs is able to call up to native functions while being embedded inside of the program and GDB provides similar functionality using Guile.

For reference, [here](http://pimpmycode.blogspot.com/2012/11/using-gnu-guile-for-fun-and-profit.html) is an example of doing this sort of thing in Guile.

Comment: You certainly *can*, just read the [docs for embedding](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/embedding.html) and the [docs for writing extensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/Writing_Racket_Extensions.html). There is an obvious question of why you would want to do this, though. As the section you linked to mentions, if you just want to call native code from Racket, [the FFI](http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/index.html) is a much simpler choice. As this question stands, I’m not sure there’s a specific question being asked, and I’m leaning towards marking it as too broad.

Comment: The reason this would be useful is because it allows the Racket code to call back to C functions without having to use a daemon or beginning the execution of the C code from within Racket and having to manually handle any sort of state the C code uses normally. The question is how it would be possible to have the extension functions as part of the main program rather than as a separate component, as the docs do not describe how to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Ah, so it is my understanding that you want to adjust the global environment without calling `load-extension` or anything similar from within Racket itself? I’m afraid I’m not familiar enough with the Racket implementation to answer that question, though it certainly seems possible. You should ask on the [Racket mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users), since the people (or perhaps person) who can answer your question are not active on Stack Overflow.